# Move button on C#

Tags: c#, button

I am working on an exercise which I have to move a button by mouse but I need to save the first location of this button.
this is my code:

```
private Point location => new Point(button1.Location.X, button1.Location.Y);
private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMouseDown = true;
    }
    private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(isMouseDown)
        {
            button1.Left = e.X + button1.Left - (button1.Width / 2);
            button1.Top = e.Y + button1.Top - (button1.Height / 2);
        }
    }
```

but location's value change after moving the button , what I have to do for save the first value.

Comment: You should follow the C# nomenclature of using an initial uppercase for properties. It help readability. So as defined, `location` is a read-only` property. Note that most C# developer use initial lowercase for variables.

Answer (score 3):

Just

```
private Point location => new Point(button1.Location.X, button1.Location.Y);
private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    isMouseDown = true;
    location.X = button1.Location.X;
    location.Y = button1.Location.Y;
}
```

If you need to save all positions then you can use a list of points

```
private List<Point> locations = new List<Point>();
private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    isMouseDown = true;
    locations.Add(new Point(button1.Location.X, button1.Location.Y)); // where locations[0] is your first point
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a function to read the `'Location'` variable, you should simply `assign` the value.

```
private Point location = new Point(button1.Location.X, button1.Location.Y);
```

Also, you need a `mouseup` event, where you set:

```
isMouseDown = false;
```

Otherwise it will be true forever.

Comment: I dont know why but when I remove new Point() , it's work